# Bit.ly API call works fine at home, but times out at work. c#

Tags: c#, connection-timeout, url-shortener, bit.ly

I have a C# project in which I make a Bit.ly API call to read the share count of my bit.ly links.  I ran the executable at home, and there is no problem reading the sharecounts of 4 different links which takes less than 4 seconds to complete.  When I take the same executable to work, and run it, the program timesout after 10 seconds on the first link.

Is this some sort of network/security thing that is causing this?  I downloaded a sample project that uses different code and it seems to work maybe 30-40% of the time; otherwise it too times out.

Confused.

Comment: You can use a WireShark to check if the correct bytes are flowing.

Comment: That's a great idea.  I keep forgetting about that program!

Comment: Gee, my question is marked down to -2??? Did I offend Bit.ly or something??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely this is an issue of security or bandwidth restriction / black lists.